# How to simulate a micrologix allen bradley PLC?

Tags: python, simulator, plc

Currently I'm working on writing data to a test machine that simulates reads from an Allen Bradley PLC in python. This machine is supposed to replicate another that we have live that simply reads the PLC tags, and I don't have any spare PLC's just lying around. Is there any program or code out there I could use to simulate a PLC for reading and writing?

This is for reading and writing tags to a simulated PLC for our test machine. I have tried using cpppo's sample code for a server, however the tag names in the live PLC has "[]" in the name (so for example, "tag[1] tag[2] etc..), and cpppo fragments these whenever I try to instantiate them in the terminal.

I expect there to be some simulator that exists that should solve this problem, however I have been searching for more than a week now with no hope/leads besides cpppo, any kind of insight or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Logix 500 Emulate is what you want, and it's free.

Go to the RA downloads site, and then search for "Emulate".
[Rockwell Automation - Downloads](https://compatibility.rockwellautomation.com/Pages/MultiProductDownload.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the software along with rslinx classic as they seem to go hand-and-hand. I haven't gotten anything to work but this is all very new to me so I might need a while to understand it. any tips to just swiftly jump in and start an emulated server up? Along with any other programs ill have to install along side it?